# Creating rhel iso with custom rpm

Tags: centos, rpm, rhel, rhel6

I have added my package under Packages folder in iso . Then i have updated repodata. Later i have created a group my-packages and added it in %package section in kickstart file at the end . But when i install the iso, and see the `/root/install.log`,mine packages are not install at the end . Thus it causing use of system os command in error . 
How to add our own rpm's after installtion of base os rpm's,so that i can access all system os command in my rpm .
And again how to specify the installation order of rpm .

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up a http mirror (local or remote), and put your rpm under "Packages".

- Add your mirror as a repo on your kickstart (repo directive)
- Then append your package name in the "%packages" session:

Example:

Pcakage file: `mypackage.rpm`

Mirror: `MyMirror.com` or (Ip address pointing to your local http server on the same network as the machine being installed)

The repo directive:

```
repo --name="MyRepo"  --baseurl=http://MyMirror.com
```

Packages section:

```
%packages
@base
mypackage # without .rpm nor version
%end
```

Macke sure that "http://MyMirror.com/Packages/mypcakage.rpm" is downloadable.

Real example:

```
--repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64 --cost=100

%packages
@base
nano
%end
```

While the package url is "http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/nano-2.0.9-7.el6.x86_64.rpm"

- Another Alternative, install your rpm at the Post Install section:

If the OS being installed doesn't have "wget" add it to "%packages":

```
%post
wget http://MyMirror.com/Packages/mypcakage.rpm
rpm -i mypcakage.rpm
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: I am using a shell script which creates the iso for me . After creating the iso, the `%package` section of kickstart look like as below:

Comment: (@)base
(@)platform-rh-core
(@)platform-features
(@)appliance-product

Comment: The last group appliance-product is what should get installed at the last, so that i can access all the OS related commands in my rpm. But after looking at /root/install.log, i can see the OS not installing the packages in given order. Does it expected behaviour ?